# How to limit where an object spawns GameMaker Studio 2

Tags: game-maker, spawning

When the game starts, I am trying to generate an object in a random area. It's working, but sometimes the object spawns in the players view.

How to have an object that generates in a random location, but not in the player's view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `rectangle_in_rectangle` to check if the bounding box of the object is inside the bounding box of the camera.

```
place_object_at_random_position()
var cameraLeft = bview_xview[0]
var cameraTop = view_yview[0]
var cameraRight = view_xview[0] + view_wview[0]
var cameraBottom = view_yview[0] + view_hview[0]
while (rectangle_in_rectangle(bbox_left, bbox_top, bbox_right, bbox_bottom, 
                              cameraLeft, cameraTop, cameraRight, cameraBottom)) {
    place_object_at_random_position()
}
```

If you for some reason cannot access the object's bounding box (`bbox_left` etc.) you can use `point_in_rectangle` instead.

```
var x = random_range(min, max)
var y = random_range(min, max)
var cameraLeft = bview_xview[0]
var cameraTop = view_yview[0]
var cameraRight = view_xview[0] + view_wview[0]
var cameraBottom = view_yview[0] + view_hview[0]
while (point_in_rectangle(x, y, cameraLeft, cameraTop, cameraRight, cameraBottom)) {
    x = random_range(min, max)
    y = random_range(min, max)
}

create_object_at(x, y)
```

The functions `place_object_at_random_position` and `create_object_at` are functions you define yourself.